# Query to combine each duplicate found entry

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Hey all I am wanting to create a query so that I can combine each of the found duplicates into one entry.

An example of this is:

```
 Name        | ID    | Tag   | Address           |carNum
 -------------------------------------------------------
 Bob Barker  |2054   |52377  |235 Some road      |9874
 Bill Gates  |5630   |69471  |014 Washington Rd. |3700
 Bob Barker  |2054   |97011  |235 Some road      |9874
 Bob Barker  |2054   |40019  |235 Some road      |9874
 Steve Jobs  |8501   |73051  |100 Infinity St.   |4901
 John Doe    |7149   |86740  |7105 Bull Rd.      |9282
 Bill Gates  |5630   |55970  |014 Washington Rd. |3700
 Tim Boons   |6370   |60701  |852 Mnt. Creek Rd. |7059
```

In the example above, **Bob Barker** and **Bill Gates** are both in the database more than once so I would like the output to be the following:

```
 Bob Barker|2054|52377/97011/40019|235 Some road     |9874
 Bill Gates|5630|69471/55970      |014 Washington Rd.|3700
 Steve Jobs|8501|73051            |100 Infinity St.  |4901
 John Doe  |7149|86740            |7105 Bull Rd.     |9282
 Tim Boons |6370|60701            |852 Mnt. Creek Rd.|7059
```

Notice how **Bob Barker** & **Bill Gates** *appends the tag row (the duplicated data)* into one row instead of having multiple rows. This is because I do not want to have to check the previous ID and see if it matches the current id and append to the data.

I am hoping a SQL query guru would have a query to do this for me!

**Code from another [forum](http://forums.sqlteam.com/t/ms-sql-2012-query-to-combine-each-duplicate-found-entry/4176/2)**

```
  SELECT [USER],  
    STUFF(b.[licenseDup],1,1,'')                                            AS licenseDup, 
    STUFF(c.[yearDup],1,1,'')                                               AS yearDup,
    STUFF(d.[makeDup],1,1,'')                                               AS makeDup,
    STUFF(e.[modelDup],1,1,'')                                              AS modelDup,
    STUFF(f.[colorDup],1,1,'')                                              AS colorDup
  FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT a.*            FROM [FEBCardb].[dbo].[sheet1$]         AS a)           AS a
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT '/' + b.[License]       FROM [FEBCardb].[dbo].[sheet1$]         AS b            WHERE a.[User] = b.[User]   FOR XML PATH('')) b(licenseDup)
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT '/' + b.[Year]          FROM [FEBCardb].[dbo].[sheet1$]         AS b            WHERE a.[User] = b.[User]   FOR XML PATH('')) c(yearDup)
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT '/' + b.[Vehicle Make]  FROM [FEBCardb].[dbo].[sheet1$]         AS b            WHERE a.[User] = b.[User]   FOR XML PATH('')) d(makeDup)
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT '/' + b.[Vehicle Model] FROM [FEBCardb].[dbo].[sheet1$]         AS b            WHERE a.[User] = b.[User]   FOR XML PATH('')) e(modelDup)
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT '/' + b.[Color Name]    FROM [FEBCardb].[dbo].[sheet1$]         AS b            WHERE a.[User] = b.[User]   FOR XML PATH('')) f(colorDup);
```

This produces the following (what I see from that query above):

```
USER   |licenseDup     |yearDup   |makeDup       |modelDup         |colorDup
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
V5432E |XXXXXX/ZZZZZZZ |1998/2001 |Pontiac/Honda |Grand Am/Odyssey |Silver/Green
V5432E |XXXXXX/ZZZZZZZ |1998/2001 |Pontiac/Honda |Grand Am/Odyssey |Silver/Green
S89542 |XXXXXX         |2010      |Dodge         |Viper            |Black
```

And this is what I am looking to see:

```
USER   |licenseDup     |yearDup   |makeDup       |modelDup         |colorDup
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
V5432E |XXXXXX/ZZZZZZZ |1998/2001 |Pontiac/Honda |Grand Am/Odyssey |Silver/Green
S89542 |XXXXXX         |2010      |Dodge         |Viper            |Black
```

Comment: Are `CarNum`, `ID`, and `Address` always the same for the same `Name`? If so, this sounds like wasted space and a normalization nightmare. Why aren't the different tags stored in a separate related table?

Comment: no @AaronBertrand. The car/make/model/color (i don't have them shown in the example) as different but to make it less bulky when asking the question i just used 1 of them.

Comment: So when you collapse a row and there are different values for address, which address do you want? Don't dumb things down, always state your actual problem, including edge cases - these are often far more important than the common/simple case. Smart folks here will figure it out.

Comment: @AaronBertrand check out my updated OP.

Comment: That still doesn't tell me what you want if, say, the second row containing Bob Barker had a different address, e.g. 555 Some Other Road.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it would be the same setup. If Bob Barker had 3 address then it would be setup as it does for the tags. **235 Some road/9210 maker street/147 Pineapple street**.

Comment: Okay, please make that clear in your question, because currently it isn't. What is the only set of columns that defines what an actual duplicate is?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Please check out my updated OP with a real world example of what I am seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since performance is obviously not going to be a high priority here (all this XML PATH concatenation is quite expensive), and since the only real problem with the output is that you have duplicates, try changing this:

```
SELECT [USER],  
    STUFF(b.[licenseDup],1,1,'')    ...
  FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM [FEBCardb].[dbo].[sheet1$] ...
```

To this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [USER],  
    STUFF(b.[licenseDup],1,1,'')    ...
  FROM
    (SELECT a.* FROM [FEBCardb].[dbo].[sheet1$] ...
```